# determining how many items in a div

Tags: layout, html

I have a div in which I'm putting some items (as spans). If there are too many items, I would like a "more" link to appear, otherwise- no link.
Problem is the div's width is dynamic (it's about 20% of the page - which means I can't tell how wide exactly it is).
Question is - how to determine (preferably on client side, but might be on server side as well) if there are too many items - and instead of displaying the extra items - displaying a "more" link.

For example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oren_a/CjN24/) there are 2 extra items, which should not be displayed at first, but only after the user will click the "more" link (which still doesn't exist).

I'm not mentioning my server side language because if the problem can be solved only on server side, just a general description will be enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, embedded styles in HTML?  Eww!!  Use CSS files and `class` attributes.
Secondly, you should use `<UL>` for lists, as it seems you are trying to build a list.

To answer your question, you can easily do this with jQuery (if set an ID on your DIV):

```
var maxCount = 3;
if ($('#myDiv').find('SPAN').length > maxCount)
{
  //over max, so hide something.
}
```

But really it should be more like (where myList is an ID of an unordered list):

```
var maxCount = 3;
if ($('#myList').children().length > maxCount)
{
  //over max, so hide something.
}
```

Comment: First about embedded styles in HTML -  I was gonna refactor that. Honestly :-).  
About the rest - please refer to my answer to Vik David. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you have too many unknowns, so there is nothing you can do about it.  You have to be able to find out what fits and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common feature. [Here's a jQuery plug-in called lessMore to do it](http://webcloud.se/log/Building-jQuery-plugins/). You would call it like so:

```
$('#content').lessMore({
    limit: 5,
    numbers: false
});
```

Using an existing plug-in is better for code-reuse and you avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I may be missing out on something here, but as I mentioned in the question, I DON'T KNOW the width of the containing div (and I also don't know which items will be displayed), and so I don't know how many items will fit in.